# What is the equivalent of Request::route() in Laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

In Laravel 3 we could call `Request::route()` to get the main route handling the request.

Is there any equivalent in Laravel 4?

Example of L3 code:

```
// in route.php
Route::any('TestRoute/(:any)', array('as' =>  'NamedRoute', function() {
    return print_r(Request::route());
}));
```

When we visit

```
http://servername/TestRoute/123
```

we get

```
Laravel\Routing\Route Object ( 
    [uri] => TestRoute/(:any) 
    [method] => GET 
    [bundle] => application 
    [controller] => 
    [controller_action] => 
    [action] => Array (
        [as] => NamedRoute
        [0] => Closure Object ( ) 
        [https] => 
    )
    [parameters] => Array ( [0] => 123 ) 
)
```

I am only interested to get the name of a Named Route from the above Object:

```
$namedRoute = $Route->action['as'];
```

Comment: Im sure you can tailor anything you want with this infos -> http://laravel.com/api/classes/Illuminate.Routing.Router.html

Comment: `Router` class has a method `currentRouteName()`. That's probably what you're looking for.

Comment: @arma: Router class has all the functionality I need. thnx

Comment: @package: Route::currentRouteName() returns the name of a Named Route. Thnx

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you might be interested in `Route::currentRouteName();`. This get's the name of the route that is currently running.

http://laravel.com/docs/routing#named-routes